# Bootstrap dropdown issues. (Dropdowns ans remains dropdowned)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I want to use bootstrap dropdown menu:

```
<li class="nav__item dropdown profile open">
                        <a id="openLessons" href="#" class=" nav__link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Открытые уроки
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu newmenu">
                            <li class=""><a href="/algebra">Алгебра</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="/literature">Литература</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="/russian">Русский язык</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="/history">История</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

For some reason it's dropdowned when the page loads and rmains dropdowned.
What have I forgotten?
[Fiddle of course.](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/3389/)

Comment: I removed the class open in your fiddle. The dropdown got closed. But it is not opening on clicking the anchor tag. Why?

Comment: Okay. I get it. You did not include jquery 2.1.0

Comment: Also you need tor emove href='a' from first link. Someone has answered it, but deleted his answer)

Comment: I did include of jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove** `.open`

`<li class="nav__item dropdown profile open">`

Answer (score 1):

```
<li class="nav__item dropdown profile open">
```

remove the class open.